# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS VM's resolution on VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, resolution, ubuntu-22.04

So, I'm working on VirtualBox 6.1, I have a Ubuntu 22.04 LTS VM, I have installed LinuxGuestAdditions 6.1.26 on my VM and can pick a resolution and have bidirectional clipboard BUT when I changed my resolution to 1920x1080 it stays stuck on the top left corner of my VM window

[image: Screenshot]

I have tried using different graphic controller options (settings, display, graphics controller) but every option other than the default one (VMSVGA) is labeled as an invalid setting and would yield a gray screen when I open my VM.

Comment: If I may ask, why use VirtualBox 6.1 and not the latest 7.0.8? (I have Ubuntu 22.04 on VirtualBox 7.0.8 and do not have the issue. Not saying you won't, but why using an older version?)

Comment: @YisroelTech it is simply the version I've had for a while and I assumed there would be no issues with it

Comment: Try upgrading VBOX and using the upgraded VBOX guest extensions.

Comment: @John In my experience VirtualBox get fuzzy if it gets notice of an update.

Answer (score 1):

What John said simply worked. Upgrading to VirtualBox 7.0.8 fixed the issue.

I didn't have to install another VBoxLinuxAdditions either or do any action on my VM side, just using a recent VB version worked.